# Why won't my Threads die and cause a memory leak?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, executor

An app of mine is accumulating a lot of `Thread` instances that the GC can't pick up and clear out. This memory leak crashes the app in the long run.

I'm not *100%* sure where they come from, but I have a distinct feeling the following *might* be the code in question:

```
public class UraHostHttpConnection extends AbstractUraHostConnection {
    private Handler uiThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    private Executor taskExecutor = new Executor() {
         public void execute(Runnable command) {
             new Thread(command).start();
        }
    };
    private ConnectionTask task = null;

    @Override
    public void sendRequest(final HttpUriRequest request) {
        this.task = new ConnectionTask();
        this.uiThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                task.executeOnExecutor(taskExecutor, request);
            }
        });
   }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        if (this.task != null)
            this.task.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

This code allows me to run several HTTP connections in parallel that won't block each other on the default `AsyncTask` `Executor` (which is just a single threaded queue).

I checked, that the `AsyncTask`s are in fact reaching their `onPostExecute()` methods and don't just run forever. After inspecting some memory dumps I suspect the wrapping `Thread`-Objects to not stop running after the `AsyncTask`s are completed.

Is it possible that the above code is still responsible for my memory leak, or should I start looking elsewhere?

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** It should be noted, that `sendRequest` is only ever called once. Other parts of the code not in the sample above make sure of that.

**Edit 2:** the super-class looks like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractUraHostConnection {
    protected IUraHostConnectionListener listener = null;

    public void setListener(IUraHostConnectionListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    public abstract void sendRequest(HttpUriRequest request);
    public abstract void cancel();
}
```

The AsyncTask looks like this:

```
private class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<HttpUriRequest, Object, Void> {
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    private ByteArrayBuffer receivedDataBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(524288);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(HttpUriRequest... arg0) {
        UraHostHttpConnection.taskCounter++;
        AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("IVU.realtime.app");
        try {
            // Get response and notify listener
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(arg0[0]);
            this.publishProgress(response);

            // Check status code OK before proceeding
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                int readCount = 0;

                // Read one kB of data and hand it over to the listener
                while ((readCount = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1 && !this.isCancelled()) {
                    this.receivedDataBuffer.append(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    if (this.receivedDataBuffer.length() >= 524288 - 2048) {
                        this.publishProgress(receivedDataBuffer.toByteArray());
                        this.receivedDataBuffer.clear();
                    }
                }

                if (this.isCancelled()) {
                    if (arg0[0] != null && !arg0[0].isAborted()) {
                        arg0[0].abort();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // forward any errors to listener
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.publishProgress(e);
        } finally {
            if (httpClient != null)
                httpClient.close();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... payload) {
        // forward response
        if (payload[0] instanceof HttpResponse)
            listener.onReceiveResponse((HttpResponse) payload[0]);
        // forward error
        else if (payload[0] instanceof Exception)
            listener.onFailWithException((Exception) payload[0]);
        // forward data
        else if (payload[0] instanceof byte[])
            listener.onReceiveData((byte[]) payload[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listener.onReceiveData(this.receivedDataBuffer.toByteArray());
        listener.onFinishLoading();
        UraHostHttpConnection.taskCounter--;
        Log.d(TAG, "There are " + UraHostHttpConnection.taskCounter + " running ConnectionTasks.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure, but can this help you? http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/activitys-threads-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Anything in the constructors of the super-classes of AbstractUraHostConnection that might be spooking? Also how does ConnectionTask look?

Comment: Added code of both classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute a ThreadPoolExecutor for your Executor so that you have control over the size of the pool.  If ThreadPoolExecutor is basically an Executor with exposed methods, it may just be a case where the default maximum pool size is set very high.

Official doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Take a look in particular at:

```
setCorePoolSize(int corePoolSize)
//Sets the core number of threads.

setKeepAliveTime(long time, TimeUnit unit)
//Sets the time limit for which threads may remain idle before being terminated.

setMaximumPoolSize(int maximumPoolSize)
//Sets the maximum allowed number of threads.
```

There's also an alternative if you want to code less (better idea depending on how much control you really want and how much code you'll trade to get it).

```
Executor taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(x);
```

where x = the size of your pool

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that solves the issue. But out of curiosity I'm wondering what goes wrong in my code. Killing unresponsive threads after a while is not a particularly elegant solution :-)

Comment: Answer edited for an alternative.  Threads *should* be GCed automagically, but as we know, GC does what GC does, when it wants to, even when we ask directly.  I wish I knew more about the underlying mechanism, but they don't call me Kludge for nothing...  Also, limiting the pool should keep you from having to hunt down zombies on your own.